# How can I speed up xmlhttp requests (VBA)? Should I be using arrays?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

For my work, I regularly need to compare a table of ~2000 meds to a website to see whether their substance IDs (an 8-digit number) still exist / have changed. I tried to automate the process using VBA (allowed at work because it comes with excel) and xmlhttprequests. I got it to work, but the process is ever so slow (sometimes excel freezes for up to 10 minutes) and I want to speed things up. Mind you, I'm only an amateur and not a programmer.

This is my code:

```
Sub PZN_Check_XHR()

Dim xmlhttp As Object
Dim url As String
Dim pzn As String
Dim ZelleA As Range
Dim ZelleB As Range
Dim a As Range


Set a = Worksheets("Treatments").Range("H2:H" & Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row)
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")

'Begin Loop, define PZN (substance IDs), define cells
For Each ZelleA In a
    pzn = ZelleA.Value
    Set ZelleB = Cells(ZelleA.Row, 10)
    Set ZelleC = Cells(ZelleA.Row, 8)

    'Add a link to our intranet database for all the substance IDs in Column H)
    If ZelleC.Value <> 0 Then
        ZelleC.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ZelleC, Address:="http://ukb648/list.php?st=" & pzn & "&aufruf=1"
    End If


    'URL of the website I want to check
    url = "https://www.arzneimittel-datenbank.de/search/" & pzn

    xmlhttp.Open "GET", url, True
    xmlhttp.Send
    Do While xmlhttp.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

       If InStr(1, xmlhttp.responseText, "<title>Arzneimittel-Datenbank") <> 0 Then
            ZelleB.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            ZelleB.Value = "PZN not found"
            ZelleB.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ZelleB, Address:="http://ukb648/list.php?st=" & Left$(Worksheets("Treatments").Cells(ZelleA.Row, 2), InStr(1, Worksheets("Treatments").Cells(ZelleA.Row, 2), " "))
        Else
            'Print result to ZelleB
            ZelleB = Mid(xmlhttp.responseText, InStr(1, xmlhttp.responseText, "<title>") + 7, (InStr(1, xmlhttp.responseText, "</title>") - InStr(1, xmlhttp.responseText, "<title>") - 32))
            ZelleB.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            Worksheets("Treatments").Cells(ZelleA.Row, 11) = Worksheets("TradeNames").Cells(ZelleA.Row, 3)
            Worksheets("Treatments").Cells(ZelleA.Row, 12) = Worksheets("TradeNames").Cells(ZelleA.Row, 5)
    End If

Next ZelleA

End Sub
```

This code takes about 1-2 seconds per row to execute, and my table has about 2000 rows (and will grow to >10.000 rows in the forseeable future). Is there a way to speed this up? Maybe reading the data into an array first, and work from there? If yes, how so? Or did I screw up the loop somehow?
Thank you so much for your time!

Edit: Some sample PZNs (as requested by "Foxfire And Burns And Burns", thank you for your time): 04516999, 03300613, 02358177, 02197219, 02530357, 00886110, 03355873, 04920298

Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation yet to upvote your comments. However, I will try your ideas and provide feedback if anything works.

Comment: Your speed hit is in waiting for response from the website.  So you likely cannot do much to speed up your code.

Comment: though the use of arrays would help slightly (and i would argue its a WAAAAAY better practice then looping through sheet objects) Brian is right - most of the slowness is probably waiting on responses.

Comment: Can you post some `PZN` values?

Comment: It's also entirely likely that `arzneimittel-datenbank.de` will rate-limit you or possibly even shut you down if you try to ask for 10k searches in very short order. Therefore, no matter how efficient your VBA code, you're at their mercy.

Comment: You are sending the requests one by one, waiting for the response in `Do While ... Loop` then send next. If using async event handler, you can send multiple requests simultaneously. This article may help. http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2006/10/09/async-xmlhttp-calls/

Comment: If the PZN is found - e.g. [10121443](https://www.arzneimittel-datenbank.de/search/10121443) - then the site returns 302 (Found) with the actual location in the "Location" response header. MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP [automatically follows redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2594234/2127508) so that process will be invisible to the program. If the PZN is not found (e.g. 12345678) then the site returns 200 (OK) with a message in the response body about no search results being returned