# How to follow a search page when scaping using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am making this call in Excel VBA

```
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
            .Open "GET", "https://www.sloanex.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=" & SearchString, False
            .send
            html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With
```

The page forwards to another page
[image]

So my .responsetext is just this

```
<title>Just a moment...</title><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"><meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><style>
```

How can I follow the page the location in the response header.

Comment: tried [WinHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2596105/6241235)? [Q&A ref](https://web.archive.org/web/20120511004610/http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/adab601b-7f1e-4349-91f5-07a79d86255b) I do note there are session cookies to likely handle